# Calculate and save an average in a meta

Tags: admin

I'm asking for your help to develop a system average. I have a website video games and I created a function that automatically calculates the average for each review. It works very well. The problem is that I would like to display in my sidebar Rated 5 games. Unfortunately, I can not ask WP to calculate and compare each mean. It will take a lot of time. So I'd like to do is calculated at the publication of the review in the admin to save automatically mean a meta. I do not know anything about the possibility in the administration. Is it possible? If yes, how? thank you

```
/* RATE */

function get_rate_overall($rate=bool){

    $graphics = get_field('graphics');
    $gameplay = get_field('game-play');
    $life = get_field('life');
    $sound = get_field('sound');

    $overall = $graphics + $gameplay + $life + $sound;
    $overall = $overall / 4;
    if (is_float($overall)) { $overall = number_format($overall,1); }
    if ($rate == true) { echo $overall.'/10'; }
    if ($rate == false) { echo $overall; }  
}
```

Comment: You need to show us some code. What have you tried? What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I have nothing except my writing function in the functions.php file:

This feature allows me to display the average of a review. I want this operation to be performed at the time of publishing the article and recorded in a meta. I do not really know how to work or where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this via the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpa78558_save_average_meta', 100 );

function wpa78558_save_average_meta( $post_id ) {

    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

        $graphics = get_field('graphics', $post_id);
        $gameplay = get_field('game-play', $post_id);
        $life = get_field('life', $post_id);
        $sound = get_field('sound', $post_id);

        $overall = $graphics + $gameplay + $life + $sound;
        $overall = $overall / 4;
        if (is_float($overall)) { $overall = number_format($overall,1); }

        update_post_meta($post_id, 'overall', $overall);

    }

}
```

You can add additional checks in here for a specific post type (see example on `save_post` codex page), or verify that your field values exist before saving the meta data.

The average will be saved under the meta key `overall` and can be output in the template or referenced in a query.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try and I'll let you know. thank you again